# Angular 5 - Find objects in array and create new array with those objects found

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have the following array with objects. Im trying to find the object with **type** "**noActiveServiceDashboard**" and **type** "**extraAmountDashboard**" and create a new array of objects in the **same format** with only these two entries.

Ive tried using **.find()** or **.filter()** but I cant access the properties inside.

```
cmsContentModules: Array<{}>
let filteredModules: Array<{}> = cmsContentModules;

filteredModules 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {cid: "2462437627203", tipo: "Funcional", Titulo: "bannerDashboard", type: "bannerDashboard", literalTitle: "Jazztel rápido y fácil", …}
1: {cid: "2462444315058", tipo: "Funcional", Titulo: "noActiveServiceDashboard", type: "noActiveServiceDashboard", literalTitle: "Hola", …}
2: {cid: "2462396510226", tipo: "Funcional", type: "dashboardLineSelector", idCmsLinkItems: "2462397143052", literalErrorSubtitle: "No se puede cambiar el servicio activo", …}
3: {cid: "2462396519886", tipo: "Funcional", type: "extraAmountDashboard", gasto: "Gasto extra:", idCmsLinkDetailedUsagePage: "2462417671130", …}
4: {cid: "2462396619049", tipo: "ArrayModulos", ModulosArray: Array(14), type: "consumptionsCounters"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to use **.filter()**

```
filteredModules.filter(
      module => 
        module["type"] === "noActiveServiceDashboard" || module["type"] === "dashboardLineSelector"
    );
```

You can access the variables putting the key of the value your searching for inbetween [].